# How to go about adding row values in sequence a certain number of times and filling in every row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, increment, seq, repeat

I have been attempting to use R to clean some data. My data set looks like this:

```
DateTime             Day ...
2018-10-01 10:00:00  0
2018-10-01 10:00:05  0
2018-10-01 10:00:10  0
2018-10-01 10:00:15  0
2018-10-01 10:00:20  0
2018-10-01 10:00:25  0
2018-10-01 10:00:30  0
2018-10-01 10:00:35  0
```

It's in 5 second bins so 24 hours = 17280 bins. I'm trying to add a `Day` column that basically just gives a value starting at the beginning as `1` and counts through 24 hours and gives `'1,1,1,1,1...1'` for Day 1 and `'2,2,2,2,2...2'` starting at `10:00:00` on Day 2 for each day and goes all the way through each data set.

So my desired output would look something like this:

```
DateTime             Day 
2018-10-01 10:00:00  1
2018-10-01 10:00:05  1
2018-10-01 10:00:10  1
2018-10-01 10:00:15  1
...        ...       ...
2018-10-02 9:59:50   1
2018-10-02 9:59:55   1
2018-10-02 10:00:00  2  
2018-10-02 10:00:05  2
...        ...       ...
2018-10-03 9:59:50   2
2018-10-03 9:59:55   2
2018-10-03 10:00:00  3  
2018-10-03 10:00:05  3
```

To do this, I came up with a code to create a vector of numbers using `rep()`:

```
days<- round(nrow(df)/17280)
sdays <- rep(1:days, each = 17280, times = 1)
df$Day <- sdays
```

This works if the days are exactly matched for 24 hour day lengths and I didn't need to round down or up. However, not each data set I'm going through has perfect 24 h date ranges and I prefer not to edit out data as each bin is necessary for what I'm looking at. So, I have been trying to figure out a more appropriate approach for this but with little success (although I'm sure it's somewhere in the www since its pretty basic).

Comment: create a `difftime` in days? `difftime(df$DateTime, df$DateTime[1], units =                    "days")`

Comment: @Wimpel It will return `[1] 0.000000e+00 5.787037e-05 1.157407e-04 ... 1.999942 2.000000 2.000058`

Comment: @utubun just round it up...

Comment: @Wimpel and add 1 to the first entry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cut()` `date` by `24 hours`:

#### Data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(ISOdatetime(2018, 10, 01, 10, 0, 0, "GMT"), 
             ISOdatetime(2018, 10, 03, 10, 0, 5, "GMT"),
             by = 5
             ))
```

#### Cut Dates by 24 hours

```
dat$Day <- cut(dat$Date, "24 hours", F)
```

#### Output

```
head(dat, 4)

dat[(nrow(dat) %/% 2 - 2):(nrow(dat) %/% 2 + 1), ]

tail(dat, 4)

                 Date Day
    1 2018-10-01 10:00:00   1
    2 2018-10-01 10:00:05   1
    3 2018-10-01 10:00:10   1
    4 2018-10-01 10:00:15   1
      .......................
17279 2018-10-02 09:59:50   1
17280 2018-10-02 09:59:55   1
17281 2018-10-02 10:00:00   2
17282 2018-10-02 10:00:05   2
      .......................
34559 2018-10-03 09:59:50   2
34560 2018-10-03 09:59:55   2
34561 2018-10-03 10:00:00   3
34562 2018-10-03 10:00:05   3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is certainly what I was looking for. I don't think `cut()` would have ever occurred to me. Does the format of the date-time matter? I currently have it in POSIXct.

Comment: Try it on a subset of your data. I think it must work. At least `cut.POSIXt()` is a standard `base` function, defined for this class.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again.

Comment: So, it worked on my data in POSIXct. I was also able to subset my data further into 12 h sections using the same method.

Answer (score 0):

just use a simple difftime caluculation, and round up to the nearest integer..

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-10-01 10:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
             as.POSIXct("2018-10-03 10:00:05", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
             by = 5
  ))
```

**code**

```
dat$day <- as.numeric( ceiling( difftime( dat$Date, dat$Date[1] - 5, units = "days") ) )
```

**output**

```
#                      Date day
#     1 2018-10-01 10:00:00   1
#     2 2018-10-01 10:00:05   1
#     3 2018-10-01 10:00:10   1
#     4 2018-10-01 10:00:15   1
#     5 2018-10-01 10:00:20   1
#     6 2018-10-01 10:00:25   1 
# ....
# 17278 2018-10-02 09:59:45   1
# 17279 2018-10-02 09:59:50   1
# 17280 2018-10-02 09:59:55   1
# 17281 2018-10-02 10:00:00   2
# 17282 2018-10-02 10:00:05   2
```